# How could I insert the same word one per line in a new file using vim?

Tags: vim

I love the substitute command, but it only works when I already have lines in a file to operate on. I would like to start a new file in vim and insert say `'FILE1:'` on the first 100 lines of the file.

The reason for this is I wrote a Perl script that will interleave the lines in file1 and file2. So I am making test files but couldn't find a command that would insert 100 lines into a new file. I understand I could simply hold `<ENTER>` and then use the substitute command, but there must be some sort of `insert` command in vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prepend the insert command (`i`) with a number and it will insert what ever you type that number of times after you exit insert mode.

So in vim type the following where `<CR>` means press enter and `<ESC>` means press escape.

```
100iFILE:<CR><ESC>
```

Note: You might need to wait a little bit for all 100 to appear after pressing `<ESC>` You will also end up with an extra new line at the end of the file which you can delete with `dd`

Comment: Note: the reason this works is because pretty much any Vim command or motion can be repeated arbitrarily by prepending a count. Examples: you can delete a line with `dd`, move to the next word with `w`, or replace all q's on a line with x's with `:s/q/x/g<CR>`. You can then delete five lines with `5dd`, move to the word after next with `2w`, or replace all q's on the next three lines with x's wiht `3:s/q/x/g<CR`.

Answer (score 2):

Insert `FILE1:` and then go to a new line. Then type `99.` to repeat what you just did 99 times.

Answer (score 1):

Just have an alternative way of doing this in my mind....

Creates 100 blank lines:

```
99o<ESC>
```

Make a visual block:

```
<C-v>gg
```

Insert word:

```
<S-i>Word<ESC>
```

Then you have 100 lines of "Word", hope this helps!

Comment: You can repeat the contents of an insertion command, too! So this can be simplified to `100oWord<ESC>`, though you'll end up with an extra line at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the rest of these answers, you can just write the first line and then paste it 99 times to make 100 lines:

```
LINE:<Esc>yy99p
```

And it's 1 character shorter!